# Recursive solution doesn't iterate correctly

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search, recursion

I'm working through a toy problem in Ruby: how to produce all possible 10-digit phone numbers where each successive number is adjacent to the last on the keypad. I've represented the adjacent relationships between numbers, and have a recursive function, but my method isn't iterating through the whole solution space. It's just finding the first solution and returning.

Here's my code:

```
adjacencies = { 1 => [2, 4],
                2 => [1, 3, 5],
                3 => [2, 6],
                4 => [1, 5, 7],
                5 => [2, 4, 6, 8],
                6 => [3, 5, 9],
                7 => [4, 8],
                8 => [5, 7, 9, 0],
                9 => [6, 8],
                0 => [8]
              }

def append_number(partial_phone_number, to_append, adjacencies)
  phone_length = 10
  partial_phone_number = partial_phone_number + to_append.to_s
  if (partial_phone_number.length == phone_length)
    return partial_phone_number
  else
    adjacencies[to_append].each do |a|
      return append_number(partial_phone_number, a, adjacencies)
    end
  end
end

(0..9).each do |n|
  puts append_number("", n, adjacencies)
end
```

And here is the output when I run it:

```
0852121212
1212121212
2121212121
3212121212
4121212121
5212121212
6321212121
7412121212
8521212121
9632121212
```

Comment: It looks like you are telling it to do it 10 times (0..9) and it is doing it 10 times?

Comment: I dont know the first thing about ruby, but if this part [adjacencies[to_append].each do |a|
      return append_number(partial_phone_number, a, adjacencies)] isnt a for on all adjacent numbers, then it should be!

Comment: @AshkanKzme it is– I checked.

Comment: Could you mention what is the expected output?

Comment: Here's a Gist with my modified code which now runs correctly, but produces duplicate values which I then remove using Array#uniq: https://gist.github.com/bee4eab8243ee22ea488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you enter the `adjacencies[to_append].each`, you immediately `return` from the method, therefore the loop will never be executed more than once.

You need to

1. return a list of phone numbers instead of just a single phone number
2. build that list somehow in your recursive call

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of your recursive method. `FIRST_DIGIT` is an array of possible first digits of an `n`-digit phone number, `n` being the first argument of the method `recurse`. You wish to determine `recurse(10)`.

```
ADJ = { 1 => [2, 4],
        2 => [1, 3, 5],
        3 => [2, 6],
        4 => [1, 5, 7],
        5 => [2, 4, 6, 8],
        6 => [3, 5, 9],
        7 => [4, 8],
        8 => [5, 7, 9, 0],
        9 => [6, 8],
        0 => [8]
      }

FIRST_DIGIT = (1..9).to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def recurse(n, nxt=FIRST_DIGIT)
  nxt.each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
    is = i.to_s
    if n==1
      a << is
    else
      recurse(n-1, ADJ[i]).each { |s| a << is + s }
    end
  end
end
```

```
recurse 1
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"] 
recurse 2
  #=> ["12", "14", "21", "23", "25", "32", "36", "41", "45", 
  #    "47", "52", "54", "56", "58", "63", "65", "69",
  #    "74", "78", "85", "87", "89", "80", "96", "98"] 
recurse 3
  #=> ["121", "123", "125", "141", "145", "147",
  #    "212", "214", "232", "236", "252", "254", "256", "258",
  #    "321", "323", "325", "363", "365", "369",
  #    "412", "414", "452", "454", "456", "458", "474", "478",
  #    "521", "523", "525", "541", "545", "547", "563", "565",
  #    "569", "585", "587", "589", "580",
  #    "632", "636", "652", "654", "656", "658", "696", "698",
  #    "741", "745", "747", "785", "787", "789", "780",
  #    "852", "854", "856", "858", "874", "878", "896", "898", "808",
  #    "963", "965", "969", "985", "987", "989", "980"] 
recurse(10).size
  #=> 117529
```

**[Edit:** the OP has asked about the possibility of modifying the code to avoid loops. This would not be difficult. The same modification could be used to enforce other rules as well (e.g, no `666`), all of which would reduce the numbers of combinations to be considered. We could do this by adding an argument `so_far` to `recurse` that is an array (or it could be a string) of all digits selected so far:

```
def recurse(n, so_far=[], nxt=FIRST_DIGIT)
  nxt.each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
    is = i.to_s
    if n==1
      a << is
    else
      < construct array 'permitted' from ADJ[i] and other rules > 
      recurse(n-1, so_far+[i], permitted).each { |s| a << is + s }
    end
  end
end
```

Note that having two arguments with defaults is not a problem, as `recurse` will initially be called with only the first argument and thereafter will be called with all three arguments.

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious how this trades off visibility of the previous digits in a single phone number. How would you modify this code in order to make sure there were no loops of length 2 (i.e., to prevent phone numbers like "1212121212"?

Comment: Also, your variable names are making it very difficult for me to understand your intent. I'm still trying to figure out how this works.

Comment: To better understand how the recursion works, you may find it helpful to add some `puts` statements to my code.  For example, you might insert `puts "n=#{n}, nxt=#{nxt}"` before the first line of the method `recurse`, insert `puts "i=#{i}, a=#{a}"` after that line, and so on.

Comment: Duncan, I've made an edit to address your question about loops. Regarding variable names, `i` is an element of `FIRST_DIGIT`, `a` is an initially-empty array being built by `each_with_object` and `is` is `i` converted to a string. `recurse(n-1, ADJ[i])` returns an array of strings; each of those strings is represent by `s` in `each`'s block. Yes, the variable names are terse, but as you gain greater experience with Ruby that may be to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement in the `each` iterator bails out of the recursive call on the first iteration. Do not use `return` there.  One possible solution is to append the result to a list (which you pass by argument) when you get to the recursive base case.